# Preventing flask from printing new line in a loop

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I am trying to produce table headings using loop in flash but I get new lines after each:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Portfolio overview
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{% for variable in variables -%}
    {% for key, value in variable.items() -%}
    <table>
       <thead><th>{{ key }}</th></thead>
    {% endfor -%}
    {% for key, value in variable.items() -%}    
    <tbody>    
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tbody>            
    {% endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
    </table>
<h2>Cash available (US$): {{ cash }}</h2>
<h2>Total portfolio value (US$): {{ wealth }}</h2>    

{% endblock %}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNCo8.jpg)

However, I would like to get this 
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k69lN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot;

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Portfolio overview
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<table>
    {% for variable in variables %}
        <thead>
            {% for key, value in variable.items() %}
                <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for key, value in variable.items() %}    
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>            
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<h2>Cash available (US$): {{ cash }}</h2>
<h2>Total portfolio value (US$): {{ wealth }}</h2>    

{% endblock %}
```

I just fixed up the placement of your for loops.